# Android MediaPlayer suddens stops playing streams

Tags: android, media-player

I am using the Android's default MediaPlayer to play audio streams. I am facing a problem wherein the stream stops after sometime and doesn't recover post that. If I stop the MediaPlayer object and then again call a Play on it, the same stream plays fine. This means that the Stream was up but my MediaPlayer somehow stopped playing it and never recovered

Is there some solution to this? Can I detect when does my MediaPlayer stops receving and playing data so that I can reinitiate the player?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for errors using onErrorListener
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html

In my app, I start a progress dialog that says "Recovering". Meanwhile I reinitialise my media Player and seekTo the time it reached before the error, then I dismiss the dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the reply !! However I have observed at a lot of times, the music stops but the OnError Listener is not called at that point..Any other ways to capture this event?

Comment: You might be experiencing buffering? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener.html